# LotusScript ODBC and string Data, right truncation error

Tags: sql, lotusscript

I have below code, wherein I am getting error "String Data, right truncation" at line adoCmd.Execute.
I have also table datatype as attached. Actually I am trying to move attachment from local drive to sql in binary format.

Can anyone please guide what is wrong here. the destination file is .PNG type.

[image]

```
Sub CreateTableRecord(keyaudit As String, Attachmentfound As Boolean, vendorname As String, VndNO As String)
        Dim adoStream               As Variant 
        Dim adoCmd                  As Variant 
        Dim strFilePath             As String
        Dim adoCon                  As Variant 
        Dim para As Variant 
        Const adTypeBinary = 1
        Const adCmdText = 1
    '   Const strDB                 As String = "SQLDB"  'Database name
    '   Const strServerName         As String = "DESKTOP-LEJN6P1"  'Server Name
        Dim strDB As String
        Dim strServerName As String 
        strServerName = "DESKTOP-LEJN6P1"
        strDB ="SQLDB"
        Dim strDir As String 

        Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set adoCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set para=CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")

        '--Open Connection to SQL server
        adoCon.CursorLocation = 3
        adoCon.open "SQLLocalConnection", "USer1", ""
        '----
        If Attachmentfound Then
            strDir = "C:\Lotus Notes work\AttachmentExtracted\"
            Dim file As Variant
            If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then strDir = strDir & "\"
            file = Dir(strDir)
            While (file <> "")

                With adoCmd
                    '.ActiveConnection = adoCon
                    adoStream.Type = adTypeBinary
                    adoStream.Open
                    adoStream.LoadFromFile strDir + file
                    MsgBox strDir + file 'It fails if file is open
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO VendorFIles VALUES (?,?,?)" ' Query
                    .CommandType = adCmdText

                    '---adding parameters
                    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("UniqueKey", 200, 1, 20, keyaudit)
                    '  Set uniquekeyval.Value = Keyaudit
                    'MsgBox adoStream.Size
                    'MsgBox  adoStream.Read
                    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("FileName", 200, 1, 200, file)
                    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("VendorAtt", 204, 1, adoStream.Size, adoStream.Read)
                    '---
                End With

                Kill strDir + file
                'do not change below this line
                file = Dir
            Wend
            Set adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoCon
            call adoCmd.Execute
            adoCon.Close
        End If
        Call updateVendorData(keyaudit, vendorname, VndNO)
end sub
```

Comment: are you aware that you are (maybe) looping through a bunch of files, but only execute the cmd at the end? so if more than one file is present, you are passing to many parameters (as I can see on a first glance)

Comment: Yes but as of now it works on only one attachment, however in real scenario it could have multiple files, so you mean I should put execute part within loop ?

Comment: yes, if you execute it outside the loop, you will not get multiple files in your table. but you say, it works for one attachment. where do you get the errors? and further, do the delete file AFTER the execute cmd

Comment: No I did not say it works for one attachment, I said even for one attachment it gives error while it goes to EXECUTE line.